# Receiving data from com port by pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I can't receive data from com port by pyserial! I have compiled program that send data and receive answer from controller correctly! I used comport monitor program to spy request and answer from controller:[correct send and answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lOt5.png)

But when I send the same request i get nothing(([my request without answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFfr7.png)
My Python prog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os
import serial, time
from serial import *
ser = serial.Serial(
     port='COM7',
     baudrate=4800,
     bytesize=5,#18,
     parity='N',
     stopbits=1,
     timeout=5,
     xonxoff=0,#
     rtscts=0,#   
     writeTimeout = 1#1
myz= '\x10\x02\x00\x00\x01\x4e\xf0\x04\x01\xff\x10\x17\x02\x4e\xf0\x04\x02\xff\x10\x17\x10\x03\xff' 
while True:
ser.write(myz) #send data
ser.readline()
```

I was trying different speeds(4800,9600) and got nothing(((
Can anybody tell me where I get mistayke?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python`  vs  `port='COM7'`  AND `bytesize=5` AND `ser.write(myz) ; ser.readline()`(so did have a fiber serial ? Time gap ?)

Comment: [Pyserial](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) may toggle the RS-232 control lines when initialised like you do, resetting your controller. Bytesize is usually 8.  Why are you "trying different speeds"? Don't you know what baudrate your controller uses? Double-check that your data is sent correctly (unicode string vs. bytes).

Answer (score 0):

You'll not receive your own message on the com port you write it to. Either connect the other side of the cable to a different port, or communicate with a device that will answer you.

Comment: On the other side i have device that must answer to me.On first picture I can see send and answer!

Comment: Are you using the same baudrate and other settings? From the screenshots, it seems different.

Also, having two devices listening to the same port may cause problems.

What device are you trying to talk to?

Comment: Yes, where you saw differenсe in port monitor? I founded manual for this device - stopbits must be '2', baudrate = '4800', bytesize = '8'. And it begun to work! The device I was trying to connect is Soviet (USSR) industrial controller 'РЕМИКОНТ Р-122 ' created in early 1970! Can you imagine this device is working on a big plan nowdays)))Crazy))) Thanks for help)